# How can one determine what a specific SQL package does?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, package

How can one determine what a specific SQL package does?

I can find the package and the job that runs it. Scripting out the job only tells me about the job, but not the package. And there appears to be no way to script out the package. I tried using SQL command

```
PRTSQLINF pkgFAA_IVRFileMods
```

or

```
EXEC PRTSQLINF pkgFAA_IVRFileMods
```

In both cases SQL Server issues error

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
>   Could not find stored procedure 'PRTSQLINF'

I ran this on Master, and MSDB databases and got same error. So, how do I find out what a specific package is doing?

Thanks, RickNPHX

Comment: SQL Server doesn't really know "packages" like Oracle - what are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to open it in the `Sql Server Business Intelligence Studio` to see what the package is actually doing.